# Android app to send Email with attachment using Java Mail API

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make a simple email app using Java Mail Android API (https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) which will send mail with an attachment. But my approach isn't working. It successfully sends the email text but doesn't add the attachment with the email.
I have added one image button to select a file for attachment. I am using Intent to select a file. Also added another button to send email.

At first by clicking on image button I am trying to select file and get the file path for the attachment. Then I am setting the file path to sendmail method for sending the mail with this attachment.

what I am doing is given below:

**Email.java**

```
package com.android.imran.emailapp003;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class Email extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private List<String> _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;


    public Email() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Email(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.size() > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.size(); i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to.get(i));
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if(_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if(_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this._body = body;
    }

    public List<String> getTo(){
        return _to;
    }
    public void setTo(List<String> toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public String getFrom(){
        return _from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from){
        this._from = from;
    }

    public String getSubject(){
        return _subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }
}
```

**ProcessEmail.java**

```
package com.android.imran.emailapp003;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

public class ProcessEmail extends AsyncTask {

    private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
    private Activity sendMailActivity;

    public ProcessEmail(Activity activity) {
        sendMailActivity = activity;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
        statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
        statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
        statusDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
            publishProgress("Processing input....");
            Email sendMail = new Email(args[0].toString(), args[1].toString());

            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            sendMail.setFrom(args[0].toString());
            sendMail.setTo((List<String>) args[2]);
            sendMail.setSubject(args[3].toString());
            sendMail.setBody(args[4].toString());
            sendMail.addAttachment(args[5].toString());

            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            sendMail.send();

            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        statusDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.imran.emailapp003;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int FILE_SELECT_CODE;
    private static int SELECT_PICTURE;
    String FilePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email);
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fromEmail = "*******@gmail.com";
                String fromPassword = "*****";
                List<String> toEmails = new ArrayList();
                toEmails.add("*******@gmail.com");
                toEmails.add("*******@live.com");
                String emailSubject = "This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.";
                String emailBody= "Email body.";
                new ProcessEmail(MainActivity.this).execute(
                        fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmails, emailSubject, emailBody, FilePath);
            }
        });

        ImageButton selectFile= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.selectFile);
        selectFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) && (resultCode == -1)) {
            FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            //Toast.makeText(this, FilePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix it out.

**Update:**
In my Genymotion emulator I've selected a file. My app shows the file path as **/external/images/images/14** in toast message.

Then when I click on the send button to send the email. I got the following error:

```
11-17 04:47:46.887  25788-26024/com.android.imran.emailapp003 E/SendMailTask﹕ IOException while sending message
    javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
    nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/14: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.Email.send(Email.java:105)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.ProcessEmail.doInBackground(ProcessEmail.java:42)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/14: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:110)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:318)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:874)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:444)
            at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:102)
            at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:897)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.Email.send(Email.java:105)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.ProcessEmail.doInBackground(ProcessEmail.java:42)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:110)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:318)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:874)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:444)
            at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:102)
            at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:897)
            at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.Email.send(Email.java:105)
            at com.android.imran.emailapp003.ProcessEmail.doInBackground(ProcessEmail.java:42)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-17 04:48:58.359  25788-25788/com.android.imran.emailapp003 W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I ran the application into my android device. I selected a file and my app showed the file path as **/document/images:52721** in toast message. But the actual path of the file is **"/Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera/01.jpg"**

I think my application doesn't getting the actual path for the attachment file. How can get the actual path for the attachment file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written this:
             :

```
        sendMail.setTo((List<String>) args[2]);
        sendMail.setSubject(args[3].toString());
        sendMail.setBody(args[4].toString());
        //sendMail.addAttachment(args[5].toString());  <- Error here 
        publishProgress("Sending email....");
        sendMail.send();

          :
```

Please uncomment the above marked lines.

Comment: Also u may try this :  [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually in my Android Studio I've run the code without commenting the line sendMail.addAttachment(args[5].toString());  But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think it can't recognize my file location. :(

Comment: ResultCode should be compared with 0

Comment: When I set resultCode == -1 my app crushes. Btw whats the reason to compare resultCode with 0?

I've updated my post, can you re check my post now?

Comment: U have to compare resultCode == RESULT_OK. When the activityForResult is called, requestCode is compared with user's request code and resultCode is compared whethear result is OK or not. So, either use 0 or RESULT_OK (Constant in Activity Class, I would prefer Result OK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get your file path:

```
   Uri selectedData = data.getData();
   String[] filePathcolumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};

   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedData, filePathcolumn, null, null, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   Log.d(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
   columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
   attachFile = selectedData.toString();
   filePath = Uri.parse(attachFile);    
   cursor.close();
```